Errors computing factorial in C++ constant expression
The first program below computes factorial using function fact. It works just fine in run-time, but constant evaluation of fact fails in the latest Visual Studio 2022 version 17.11:
constexpr int fact(const int & p) {
    int v = p - 1;
    return v ? (v+1) * fact(v) : 1;
};

int main() {
    return fact(3); // ok everywhere
}

static_assert( fact(3) ); // error in MSVC

with the error:
<source>(10): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
<source>(2): note: failure was caused by a read of an uninitialized symbol
<source>(2): note: see usage of 'v'
<source>(10): note: the call stack of the evaluation (the oldest call first) is
<source>(10): note: while evaluating function 'int fact(const int &)'
<source>(3): note: while evaluating function 'int fact(const int &)'

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vfGf4zT8q
The second example program has another implementation of factorial computing function:
constexpr int fact(const int & p) {
    int v = 0;
    v = p - 1;
    return v >= 1 ? (v+1) * fact(v) : 1;
};

It does not fail compilation even more, but instead of expected sequence:
1 2 6 24 120 720 5040

it produces during constant evaluation in MSVC the sequence of natural numbers instead:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MKPz3n1Ws
I see that some even small changes in fact implementations make the program produce correct result, but I would like to know what is wrong with the current implementations' code? Is it ill-formed in some way?

My MSVC 2022 compiles it with no errors (both in C++17 and C++20). Maybe the MSVC on Godbolt (WINE version) has some bug ? Normal MSVC is not available on Godbolt for some time now.

@wohlstad, thanks, indeed Godbolt does not have the latest MSVC compiler now, so I updated the question with screenshot from MSVC 2022, where the same error keeps happening.

I am using 17.2.5. I see that yours is 17.10. So maybe there was a regresion.

Very strange. On Godbolt it is reproducible with MSVC v19.14 and locally I can reproduce it with MSVC v19.40. So it does not look that it was ever fixed.

@Fedor -- Try release/debug for both 32-bit and 64-bit configurations.  I have seen where the 32-bit and 64-bit compilers for MSVC produce different results.

@PaulMcKenzie, in Visual Studio 2022 v17.10 it is reproducible both in x86 and x64 modes

Workaround, pass int by value instead of by const reference Demo.

Works here in msvc

Also see Why is a reference parameter in a constexpr function not a constant expression?

As already mentioned in the other answer, it is a bug or non-standard implementation of constant evaluation inside MSVC.
Upon a closer look, it seems that the issue has the same root as described in
Equal not-null pointers to distinct variables in C++ . More specifically, the pointer on the local variable from the calling recurrent function in the nested function starts magically pointing on its (different) local variable, which explains compiler errors or unexpected constant evaluations in both examples from the question.
The first example in MSVC becomes "equivalent" to something like
constexpr int fact0(const int &) {
    int v = v - 1;
    return v ? (v+1) * fact0(v) : 1;
};

constexpr int fact(const int & p) {
    int v = p - 1;
    return v ? (v+1) * fact0(v) : 1;
};

having obvious "read of an uninitialized symbol" error in int v = v - 1; for p > 1. But for p == 1 everything is fine in MSVC: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vjda34YKj
Similarly the second example is (erroneously) "transformed" by MSVC in
constexpr int fact0(const int &) {
    int v = 0;
    v = v - 1;
    return v >= 1 ? (v+1) * fact0(v) : 1;
};

constexpr int fact(const int & p) {
    int v = 0;
    v = p - 1;
    return v >= 1 ? (v+1) * fact0(v) : 1;
};

where

fact0(const int &) always returns 1 and
fact(const int & p) consequently returns (v+1) * fact0(v) = p,

explaining the sequence of natural numbers.

This seems to be msvc bug which has been in later versions. Demo.
Why is a reference parameter in a constexpr function not a constant expression?

Thanks. Any comments about the second example: https://godbolt.org/z/eohaT9naq ?

@Fedor That makes me even more sure that this is a msvc bug.

Yes, very probably, it looks as a bug or bad design inside MSVC. And could you please clarify, how the referenced SO question answers on mine?
